# Ruby-Regular expression to find index

Tags: ruby

I want to fetch the value `10` from `video[10]`. How to do this using regular expression?
I have tried : `/video\[(.*?)\]/`.
This did not work.

Comment: How did it not work? It works fine for me (e.g. `/video\[(.*?)\]/.match("video[10]")[1]` gives `"10"`).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `/video\[(.*)\]/`.

```
/video\[(.*)\]/.match "video[10]"
#=> #<MatchData "video[10]" 1:"10">
```

Comment: You need to make `.*` non-greedy: `/video\[(.*)\]/.match "video[10]]]]"
  #=> #<MatchData "video[10]]]]" 1:[10]]]">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    \b      # match a word break
    video\[ # match string
    (\d+)   # match >= 1 digits in capture group 1
    \]      # match char
    /x      # extended/free-spacing mode

"Martha, where did you put video[10]?"[r,1]
  #=> "10"
```